# Converting exported value(time) from datagridview to excel

Tags: excel, ms-access, datagridview, vb.net-2010

I have a datagridview with a lots of time-in and time-out record of employees retrieve from a table. Now i can export the data from datagridview to an excel file but im having a problem.

The time format of the column time-in and time-out is perfectly good like "9:00 AM" but when exported to excel it becomes "12/30/1899 9:00:00 AM". This was also my first problem in datagridview but i use the DGV.Columns(1).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "t" to fix the problem. Someone teach me

Comment: What does this have to do with Access?

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth im using access as db. and i dont know maybe the solution is in the db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already solve! I use this code

```
cellvalue = DGVResult.Rows(i).Cells(j).Value.ToString

Date.Parse(cellvalue).ToString("hh:mm tt").ToString
```

I use a loop catch what cell is to be formatted

Thanks for the tip!

Comment: But that will leave your times as _text_, not as _date/time_ values. Date and time as text should be avoided by all means.

Comment: but it solve my problem, exporting time value to an excel cell without unwanted data from "1899/01/01 09:00 AM" to "09:AM"

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem. Date 1899-12-30 is the *zero-value* date, and - if no date is given - a time value will always belong to the zero-date.

So, all you need is to apply a *time format* only when displaying the values.

**Addendum**

It appears, that if you enter a time only directly in Excel, it uses a zero-value date of *1900-01-01*.

So, when exporting, add two days, like:

```
Dim t As TimeSpan
Dim d As DateTime
t = New TimeSpan(14, 34, 0)   ' Your cell value.
d = New DateTime(1900, 1, 1).AddTicks(t.Ticks)
```

Then export d.

Comment: so how can i apply the time format on excel when exporting from datagridview?

Comment: You cannot apply a format, but you can try changing the value. See edit.